# What does RSD mean?

Tags: vocabulary, acronyms

This is an acronym referring to

psychological/therapeutic/social work/educational

title/degree/certification.

My Google research yields jack.

I assume R might stand for "registered" but I wouldn't bet on it.

It is one of those acronyms you can find after a name of an author/therapist. See here [LINK](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/wendela-whitcomb-marsh-salem-or/293438) for an example.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Repetitive strain disorder. Or reflex sympathetic dystrophy syndrome

Comment: The psychology clue in the link yields "rejection sensitive dysphoria" but RSD is the person's qualification, being after the name. The doctor advises about autism so perhaps Rxxx Spectrum Disorders.

Answer (score 4):

The degree of **Religious Studies Doctorate** can be abbreviated **RSD**.

Your sample [specialist with this degree](https://www.linkedin.com/in/wendela-marsh-bcba-b372b8118/) showed the RSD degree in her LinkedIn profile under Emerson Theological Institute in California.

Comment: This might be it... or not ;) Thanks for the hint. Will definitely have to check that.

Comment: Yes, THAT is it. Confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

See [AcronymFinder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/RSD.html) for 78 verified meanings of *RSD*.  If you like, continue on to [AcronymAttic.com](https://www.acronymattic.com/RSD.html) for 242 unverified meanings.
One of them (perhaps the one in the OP) is
**Rehabilitation Science Doctorate**

Comment: "Rehabilitation"... Haven't thought about that. Interesting. Thank you. Another one worth checking.